# Client-side Handlebars causes 404 requests

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

I want to use handlebars on the client side. In my html code I have calls like:

```
<img src="data/cloud/products/{{key}}/{{images.product.frontal.trans_bg_img}}" alt="">
```

directly in my index.html.

In javascript I do something like this:

```
this.emptyPageSource =  $("#productdetail").html();
this.productTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.emptyPageSource);
var html = this.productTemplate(product);
$("#productdetail").html(html);
```

which works fine. I take the existing piece of html from the dom as a template once, then apply the templating with handlebars and overwrite the old dom entry.

When I load the page, I get a lot of 404 requests, because the browser already tries to load the image resources, even if the templating wasn't invoked yet, due to the JS part.

Is there a way to evade the 404 get requests? (I'm not using angular or something alike - just plain js + jquery)

Thank you in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try converting `#productdetail` element to `<script type='text/template' id='productdetail'>`. As in: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zusemomoce/edit?html,output)

```
<h1>A Cat</h1>
<script type="text/template" id="productdetail">
<img src="{{image}}" alt="">
</script>
Rest of it

<script>
  var product =  {
    key: '1',
    image: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/freTElrZl4zaU/giphy.gif'
  }
  var emptyPageSource =  $("#productdetail").html();
  var productTemplate = Handlebars.compile(emptyPageSource);
  var html = productTemplate(product);
  $("#productdetail").replaceWith(html);
</script>
```

The browser does not understand `text/template` scripts and just ignores its. But we can read the content inside our script tag use it as a template.